# Syntax error in Javascript? (attempting to dynamically load facebook javascript sdk)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

The code below seems valid to me; do I really have a syntax error? Running this code in a console:

```
$("body").append($("<script />", {
  html: "  window.fbAsyncInit = function() { "+
"    FB.init({"+
"      appId      : '[valid_id]', // App ID"+
"      status     : true, // check login status"+
"      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session"+
"      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML"+
"    });"+
"  };"+
"  (function(d){"+
"     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];"+
"     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}"+
"     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;"+
"     js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';"+
"     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);"+
"   }(document));"
}));
```

Returns:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at it for a while, it was quite obvious ;-)

All your concatenated string parts boil done to **one line** of JavaScript code eventually – so you can’t use `// comments` in there, because the go up to where? Exactly, the end of the line!

Either strip out the comments totally – or use the `/* comment */` syntax.

Comment: Finally, someone notices! :-) Oh, and forgot a third option: Putting a line break \n at the end of each string that contains a `// comment` should also work …